# Nested subcomponents in React + rendering new data

Tags: reactjs

Help needed please,
I am currently learning react and I ran into an issues of some sort while creating a blog app.

I nested components within each other, however updated data is not received in subcomponent unless I refresh the page of the nested-component. Below is snippet of my codeWithin the AccountOverview component is another component(container) that handles a form. Once the form submits data and the backend processes the data, i expect that the AccountOverview component will render new info. However if i then go back to the parent (dashboard) and make an edit the AccountOverview component does't display newly created data except on a full-page refresh.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    state = {}
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getCurrentProfile();
    }
    render() {
        const { user } = this.props.auth;
        const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;        
        return (
            <div style={{margin: "0", padding: "0"}}>
                <Header title="Account Dashboard" />
                <section id="accountPage" className="">
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <Sidebar />
                            <main className="col-sm-9 col-md-9 account">
                                <div className="dashboard">
                                    <AccountOverviewPanel 
                                        user={user} profile={profile} loading={loading}
                                    />
                                    <PostTablePanel />
                                </div>
                            </main>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

Comment: Start by checking the browser's developer console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: no errors... I feel the issue has to do with how/where am placing my components.
here is the link to my repo (https://github.com/C0D1NGD0J0/portfolio-website-blog/tree/react/client/src/components)

Answer (score 0):

Is your submit action casusing your components to unmount. 
I tried cloning your code. it seems to miss a file for keys hence couldn't run it

Comment: keys are: secret: "random text" , and localdburl: "mongodb url"